# FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions not calling completionHandler

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, swift

I'm implementing OAuth login using Facebook SDK, but the FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler method is not calling the completionHandler nor is it returning "true", which would indicate a cached token. Everything else seems to work fine, except this. What's wrong with this code?

```
    var completionHandler: FBSessionStateHandler = {

        session, status, error in

        NSLog("token not cached");

        if error {

            // Login failed for some reason, so we notify the delegate.
            self.delegate.didFailOpenningSession?(self, withError: ErrorUtility.error(
                code: .FailedOpenningSession,
                withFacebookError: error
            ));

            // Don't proceed on errors
            return;
        }

        // Session is now open, we should notify the delegate
        self.delegate.didOpenSession?(self);
    };

    NSLog("here");

    // Open the session, prompting the user if necessary. This might send the application to the background
    if FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: completionHandler) {

        NSLog("Token cached");

        // If we end up here, the session token must exist, so we now have an open session
        self.delegate.didOpenSession?(self);
    }
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that the NSLog logs "here", but not "Token cached" nor "token not cached"

<s>Edit: Now things got a bit stranger. When my app launches I show a screen with a Facebook login button. When the user presses the button the code above gets triggered. After I authorise the app, the app gets back to the same screen (it shouldn't, but I can't do it any other way until the completion handler gets called). Then I tried pressing the button again and now I do get the logs.</s>

This is what I get:

```
    here
    token not cached
    here
```

The first line is from the first button press, the other two appear when I press it the second time. Now what's so odd about it? Shouldn't "token not cached" and "here" be reversed??? Is it calling the competionHandler from the last call or something?

Nevermind, that much is fixed.

Edit: one other thing. If I press the button multiple times, I always get "token not cached". I think it should be caching

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's solved. I was missing the method AppDelegate.application:handleOpenURL -> Bool

Comment: Good to hear you found it!

Answer (score 2):

First ensure that you are using correct closure syntax. You are not providing a matching closure callback for the block callback.

notice the block callback for the FB session is:

```
^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
```

You should have

```
    /*function parameters*/){ session, state, error in
//closure declaration goes at the top after the {

//Insert logic here
            NSLog("Token cached");
    }
```

This will equate to

```
FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(permissions, allowLoginUI:true){ session, state, error in

         //callback code body here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It did not solve the problem, however. Swift allows you to pass the last parameter like you describe, but what would the practical difference be? The closure should still be called, I think...

Comment: As long as everything is being handled correctly with setting up the Facebook SDK and such, what I've noted above should be correct and should be called back when receiving a response from the SDK (you may want to verify all of you Facebook settings and see if there's something else being called back). I didn't realize what you had above was a var declared as a closure statement being passed in. At this point you'll want to verify your Facebook settings and any other available callbacks. For simplicity and debugging, I would remove the var first... especially since it's a bit redundant.

Comment: In all honesty, what you have seems to be correct with the code provided.

Comment: I also agree =\ can't find anything wrong, but could you please see my edit?

Comment: here <- this will be called first because you're creating a variable as a callback, your log is then called, and THEN the call to the handler is made while passing in the completion closure.
token not cached is then called because of the callback... remember (this callback can be delayed. You should check if it's a timing thing or something to do with calling the FB SDK twice in a row).
    here is called again because you're calling the same code again.. same reason the first here is called

Comment: Yes, the order in which things appear is already fixed. I mean, it wasn't wrong, but when I added the changes you suggested I didn't realise I had switched the execution order. Nevermind that part. But it's not a timing thing. If I wait, nothing happens. As soon as I press the button again (that is, the Facebook UI is still triggering) I get "token not cached".

Comment: OH, make sure to store the Bool value for FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions. Because you're bridging from obj c to swift... this may be an optional that you'll have to unwrap

Comment: I have this, so it seems that it's not an optional: var isTokenCached: Bool = FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "user_birthday"], allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: completionHandler);

Comment: Hm. Error is nil, but NSLog("\(session)"); gives me this: state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed

Comment: I got it! I was missing the method AppDelegate.application:handleOpenURL -> Bool

Answer (score 2):

This usually because of missing handle seesion in app’s application:openURL function.
It is in AppDelegate.m. Description from facebook samples says below:

```
 // During the Facebook login flow, your app passes control to the Facebook     iOS app or Facebook in a mobile browser.
// After authentication, your app will be called back with the session information.
// Override application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation to call the FBsession object that handles the incoming URL
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url     sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
 annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```